# Store an image to a database using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, entity-framework

I would like to save an image (from file, `png` or `jpg`) to the database using Entity Framework.

My code is here:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Food fd)
    {
        try
        {
            FoodOrderEntities fo = new FoodOrderEntities();              


            Stream inpStream = Request.InputStream;
            Int32 length = Convert.ToInt32(inpStream.Length);

            byte[] tempImage = new byte[length];
            inpStream.Read(tempImage, 0, length);               

            //FoodImage  is an image field in the datatable, mapped by the Entity Framework
            fd.FoodImage = tempImage;                

            fo.AddToFood(fd);
            fo.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

My view is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <h2>Create</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Food",FormMethod.Post,new {enctype="multipart/form-data"})) {%>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.FoodName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FoodName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FoodName) %>
        </div>          

        <div>
            Select a file: <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

  <% } %>

   <div>
       <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
   </div>
</asp:Content>
```

But, using `Request.Files["fileUpload"]` I got only null. Then, I have used this code, but I could get only 124 bytes from my image. Instead `inpStream.Length` I have used `Request.TotalBytes` and `Request.ContentLength`, but with the same result. Please, help me! Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
alenan13

Comment: Try having `HttpPostedFilebase fileUpload` in your action parameter

Comment: Unfortunately, using fileUpload as an action parameter I again have null as fileUpload (although, thank you very much for your time and attention). My code is here:

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Food fd, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        {
            try
            {
                FoodOrderEntities fo = new FoodOrderEntities();
                if (fileUpload != null)
                {
                    Int32 length = fileUpload.ContentLength;
                    byte[] tempImage = new byte[length];
                    fileUpload.InputStream.Read(tempImage, 0, length);
                    fd.FoodImage = tempImage;
                    fo.AddToFood(fd);
                    fo.SaveChanges(); etc